# VideoDisplay.pause() doesn't work for stream

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I set `source` property to F4M file. Video starts playing. When I call `pause()` or `stop()` on `spark.components.VideoDisplay` nothing happens. Is it intended or is it a bug? Reference doesn't say any special about streams for these methods.

Comment: Try with a different encode type. Re-encode as h.264 MP4 using Handbrake and swap that with the F4M. I can confirm pausing on h.264 works using both `StageVideo` and `VideoDisplay`. You won't be able to use `VideoDisplay` with a h.264 video on iOS, however. Just want to see if it is the encode that is causing the issue here.

Comment: @JoshJanusch, I have no access to the server to change encoding.

Comment: Then stream a different video. Don't care about the source, only the video itself. Try one of the h.264 selections from here. Make sure you can stream via your browser first. A lot of the servers are either slow or no longer up. http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/index.php/download/